# success is fired before end response

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, post

As a beginner in web dev, I'm building my first web-app using pure node.js. 
In the registration part, the form data will be posted from the client-side to the server and then added to the database. The client, on success, will manipulate the DOM depending on the response it receives. However, the success callback is always fired before the response is sent.

Client-side code:

```
$.post('/register.db', {
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            if(response == register.exists){
                $(".login-form>input:nth-child(3)").append("<span>This email has already been used</span>");
            }
            else if(response == register.success){
                $(".login-wrapper>span").html("Proceed to login");
                $(".register-wrapper").html("");
            }
        }
    });
```

Server-side code:

```
                    var body = "";
                    req.on("error", function(){
                        handleError();
                    }).on("data", function(chunk){
                        body += chunk;
                    }).on("end", function(){

                        // success callback is fired as soon as request ends
                        // code afterwards is executed after success callback
                        // but response is written in db.register() function
                        var user = JSON.parse(qs.parse(body).data);
                        console.log("user ",user);
                        res.on('error', function(err){
                            handleError();
                        });
                        db.register(res, user);
                    });
```

**---Edit: added database code---**

Database code:

```
register:
        function(res, user){
            var account = user['email'];
            client.sismember('users', account, function(err, response){
                res.statusCode = 200;
                res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
                // account already exists
                if(response != 0){
                    res.write(register.exists);
                    res.end();
                    return;
                }
                client.sadd("users", account);
                client.hmset(account, "pin", user.pin, "first_name", user.first_name, "last_name", user.last_name);
                res.write(register.success);
                res.end();
                return;
            });
        }
```

Could any kind soul please point out where I went wrong? I would appreciate it a lot!!

Comment: Nothing shown in server code sends anything out. Suggest you study more tutorials

Comment: Hi charlietfl, I simply commented out the part that sends data to the database for clarity. The problem is as I said, the success callback is fired as soon as request ends, no matter what comes afterwards.

Comment: If success fires it means request has completed. If data in success is empty...it's because none was sent.

Comment: I edited the question description. In the server-side code, `console.log("user ",user);` is executed after success callback, which means db.register(), in which function the response is written,  is not even run before success.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the client-side code to below and it magically worked...I simply replaced the success callback with an anonymous callback function...Anyone knows the difference between these two ways of defining success callback?

```
$.post('/register.db',
            {
                data: JSON.stringify(user),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "text"
            },
            function(data){
                alert(data);
                if(response == register.exists){
                    $(".login-form>input:nth-child(3)").append("<span>This email has already been used</span>");
                }
                else if(response == register.success){
                    $(".login-wrapper>span").html("Proceed to login");
                    $(".register-wrapper").html("");
                }
            });
```

Comment: The documentation for `$.post()` doesn't indicate that a success callback can be specified in the `data` hash. I'm surprised to learn that it fires when specified that way, if indeed that is the case. Personally, I would always write `$.post(...).then(...)`.

Comment: In fact, the `$.post(...)` expression in the question is a complete hybrid of `$.ajax()` and `$.post()`. It's wrong in several regards.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I see. Yea I completely confused $.ajax() and $.post(). Thank you so much!